# Multi-rows Bootstrap Group Button Styling

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap button group and facing issues with its look and feel when buttons are spanned across multiple rows. Please see attached:

[image]

As you can see the button in second row doesn't have proper left border. Second row is not a table row rather it's the button element that is floated below when overflow occurred.

Is there any way we can handle it in CSS? Any solution or hint will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Source Code:

```
<div id="ReportsButtonGroup" Class="btn-group btn-group-sm " style="padding-top:15px;height:85px;overflow:hidden;">

                    <a class="btn btn-default smallBottomMargin "
                       href="javascript:void(0)"
                       title="View Slides">
                        <img src="/Content/images/Edit.png" height="20" width="20" />
                    </a>

                    <a class="smallBottomMargin btn btn-default"
                       href="javascript:void(0)"
                       title="Start a Poll using this Template">
                        <img src="/Content/images/Polling.png" height="20" width="20" />
                    </a>


                    <a class="btn btn btn-default smallBottomMargin " id="{{TemplateId}}"
                       href="javascript:void(0)"                           
                       title="Archive this content">
                        <img src="/Content/images/archiveicon.png" height="20" width="20" />
                    </a>

                    <a class="btn btn btn-default smallBottomMargin" id="{{TemplateId}}"
                       href="javascript:void(0)"                           
                       title="Associate tags with content">
                        <img src="/Content/images/tag-add.png" height="20" width="20" />
                    </a>

                    <a class="btn btn btn-default smallBottomMargin " id="{{TemplateId}}"
                       href="javascript:void(0)"                           
                       title="Associate child subscriptions with this template">
                        <img src="/Content/images/GroupOfPeople.png" height="20" />
                    </a>

                    <a class="btn btn btn-default smallBottomMargin " id="{{TemplateId}}"
                       href="javascript:void(0)"                           
                       title="Associate child subscriptions with this template">
                        <img src="/Content/images/GroupOfPeople.png" height="20" />
                    </a>

                    <a class="btn btn btn-default smallBottomMargin " id="{{TemplateId}}"
                       href="javascript:void(0)"                           
                       title="Associate participant group with this template">
                        <img src="/Content/images/ParticipantLists.png" height="20" />
                    </a>

                </div>

.smallBottomMargin{
    margin-bottom:1px !important;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it might not be a proper way to handle this scenario but it somehow resolved the issue. I'm open to better solutions, and answers but until then here is what I did to fix it.

The solution is JS based.

```
function AdjustLeftBorder() {
                            let lastButtonTopPostion;
                            $itemObj.find("#ReportsButtonGroup a").each(function (index, value) {
                                let currentElemtnTopPosition = $(this).get(0).getBoundingClientRect().y;
                                if (lastButtonTopPostion == undefined) {
                                    lastButtonTopPostion = currentElemtnTopPosition;
                                }
                                if (lastButtonTopPostion != currentElemtnTopPosition) {
                                    $(this).css("margin-left", "0px");
                                    return false;
                                }
                                else {
                                    lastButtonTopPostion = currentElemtnTopPosition;
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

We iterate over all buttons in group. As soon as we finds an element whose top position (on screen/viewport) is not equals to its prior sibling, we set the left-margin equals to 0 for that element and return false to break the each loop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know we can have CSS conditions in SASS but I believe those conditions are evaluated at design time rather at runtime. So if you manipulating(show/hide) your html elements at runtime I think SASS based solution wont work.